# Struts2 JPA Validation error how to forward to action and not lose ActionErrors messages?

Tags: validation, struts2, forward

I'm using Hibernate validator 4.1 to validate my Entity.

I have a dashboard that I can access from the action `viewDashboard`. In my action class, I set the values of two `List` like this.

```
public String execute() throws Exception {

    listDocteur = service.listDocteur();
    listUser = service.listUser();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In the DashBoard, I have a submit button that can add a User.

```
<action name="saveUser" class="com.test.action.CreateUserAction" method="execute">
   <interceptor-ref name="mybasicStackWithValidation" >
   </interceptor-ref>
   <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/viewDashboard.jsp</result>
   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">viewDashboard</result>
</action>
```

If I submit an invalid value, I'll see the error messages, but I'll lose my 2 Lists. If I have a `type="redirectAction"`, I lose the error messages.

In Struts 1, I would forward to the action `viewDashboard.do` without a `redirect` and that will works. How can i achieve this in Struts2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution. I have to use `&lt;input type="redirectAction">youraction ..`

and need to put this in your `SAVEAction`

```
<interceptor-ref name="store">
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

and finally, in your displayAction (that will display the error messages)

```
<interceptor-ref name="store">
    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

or RESTORE

Answer (score 0):

Check this may be it will help you, since redirectAction means a new request at from beginning

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070111/can-i-propagate-struts2-actionerrors-between-different-action-classes)

Answer (score 0):

[Action Chaining](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-chaining.html) may be what you are looking for.

Chaining “allows an Action to forward requests to a target Action, while propagating the state of the source Action.”

Comment: I did try the chaining.. but my messages are still not there.  I have an interceptor to validate the entity.  It found 2 errors.. log the error in the logs and forward to the input.  Even if I put &lt;result name="input" type="chain">viewDashboardConfig&lt;/result>  and &lt;interceptor-ref name="chain"/> my message are not there

Comment: Look like I can use this to store the messages between chain actions     http://glindholm.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/preserving-messages-across-a-redirect-in-struts-2/