# struts2 errors lost

Tags: validation, struts2

I trying to use struts2 validation framework. I have a ActionName-validation.xml in place. Entry in the struts.xml is as follows

```
    <action name="registerCandidateStep1" class="candidateAction"
            method="registerCandidateStep1">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
            <result name="input" type="chain">
                <param name="actionName">loadCandidateRegistrationForm</param>
                <param name="namespace">/.secureActions</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    <action name="loadCandidateRegistrationForm" class="loadCandidateFromAction"
        method="loadCandidateRegistrationForm">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
    </action>
```

on error condition request do get forwarded to "loadCandidateRegistrationForm" but i dont see error on the page. I have  included   tag in the jsp

StrutsConfig.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

        <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action" />

        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />

        <package name="org" namespace="/"
            extends="struts-default,json-default">

            <result-types>
                <result-type name="tiles"
                    class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
            </result-types>

            <global-results>
                <result name="welcome" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            </global-results>

        </package>

        <package name="org.unsecureActions" extends="org">
            <!--
                This package contains such a actions which doesn't need user logged
                in.
            -->

            <action name="welcome" method="forwardAction" class="baseAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            </action>

            <action name="logout" method="logoutCandidate" class="logoutAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            </action>

            <action name="loadAdvanceSearchForm" method="loadAdvanceSearch"
                class="advanceSearchAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">advanceSearch</result>
            </action>

            <!--Candidate workflow  actions -->
            <action name="registerCandidateStep1" class="candidateAction"
                method="registerCandidateStep1">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

                <result name="success" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
                <result name="input" type="redirect">loadCandidateRegistrationForm.action</result>
            </action>

            <action name="registerCandidateStep2" class="candidateAction"
                method="registerCandidateStep2">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
                <result name="input" type="tiles">loadCandidateRegistrationForm</result>
            </action>
            <action name="registerCandidateStep3" class="candidateAction"
                method="registerCandidateStep3">
                <result type="chain">
                    <param name="actionName">loginCandidate</param>
                    <param name="namespace">/org.unsecureActions</param>
                </result>
                <result name="input" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
            </action>

            <action name="loadCandidateRegistrationForm" class="loadCandidateFromAction"
                method="loadCandidateRegistrationForm">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <result name="success" type="tiles">registerCandidate</result>
            </action>
            <!--Candidate workflow  actions -->

            <action name="loginCandidate" class="loginAction" method="loginCandidate">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
                <result name="input" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            </action>

        </package>

        <package name="org.secureActions" extends="org">
            <!--
                This package contains such a actions which needs user must logged in
                before executing these.
            -->

            <interceptors>
                <!--
                    Following interceptor checks for is user logged in before executing
                    the action.
                -->
                <interceptor name="contextSecurityInterceptor"
                    class="org.kovid.matrimony.interceptor.ContextSecurityInterceptor">
                </interceptor>

                <!--
                    This stack is as like default stack provided ny Struts Only
                    difference is at the bottom of folowing stack where we included our
                    "contextSecurityInterceptor" interceptor.
                -->
                <interceptor-stack name="applicationStack">
                    <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="debugging" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="profiling" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="params" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="contextSecurityInterceptor" />
                </interceptor-stack>
            </interceptors>

            <!--
                Setting default stack for interceptor taking care of this packageS.
            -->
            <default-interceptor-ref name="applicationStack" />

            <action name="home" method="forwardAction" class="baseAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
            </action>

            <action name="loadAdvanceSearchForm" method="loadAdvanceSearch"
                class="advanceSearchAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">advanceSearch</result>
            </action>

            <action name="simpleSearch" method="simpleSearch" class="simpleSearchAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">search</result>
                <result name="input" type="tiles">home</result>
            </action>

            <action name="advanceSearch" method="advanceSearch" class="advanceSearchAction">
                <result name="success" type="tiles">search</result>
            </action>
            <action name="loadImage" method="loadImage" class="imageAction">
                <result name="imageData" type="stream">
                    <param name="contentType">${imageContentType}</param>
                    <param name="inputName">imageStream</param>
                    <param name="contentDisposition">filename="candidate.jpeg"</param>
                    <param name="bufferSize">${myBufferSize}</param>
                </result>
            </action>

        </package>

    </struts>
```

Answer (score 3):

Action chaining is actively discouraged, and interactions with the validation interceptor is one reason why. You might be able to sneak around it by explicitly mapping some values (like the validation messages) from one action to the next, but... don't chain actions--there's almost never a reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Like `Dave` said, `Action Chaining` is discouraged.

**[Action Chaining](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/action-chaining.html)** :

> **Don't Try This at Home**
>
> As a rule, Action Chaining is not recommended.
>   First explore other options, such as the **[Redirect After Post](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/redirect-after-post.html)**
>   technique.

And if you have good reason to use `Redirect After Post`, use the

- [Redirect Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/redirect-result.html) + [Message Store Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/message-store-interceptor.html) OR
- [Redirect Action Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/redirect-action-result.html) + [Message Store Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/message-store-interceptor.html)

Comment: i have update strutsConfig as per in the Message Store Interceptor. Please find updated the strutsConfig in original post. After doing these changes error messages are getting displayed on the server console only. On submitting the form, even with errors its moving to the "success" action. appreciate your help.

Comment: `error messages are getting displayed on the server console only`, did the action class extends `ActionSupport`?

Comment: thanks, its working with ActionSupport. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: since its a redirect action my values are getting lost. Is there an easy way to repopulate these values back again? I did find a post regarding the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287160/struts2-jpa-validation-error-how-to-forward-to-action-and-not-lose-actionerrors-m
Since its using chaining i couldn't go ahead with this.

Comment: @kunal **[Parameters in configuration results](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html)** (parameters in URL) is recommended. But and again, you should not use the `Action Chaining`. See also the **[Redirect Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/redirect-result.html)** and **[Redirect Action Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/redirect-action-result.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Life time of Errors lasts for the current Action. If you forward/redirect to another action, then the errors will be lost.

Use `session` scope instead. Place `ArrayList` in `session` and append your errors/messages.

**Action/Interceptor:**

```
Map session         = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
List<String> errors = session.get("errorMessages");

if(errors==null)
   session.put("errorMessages", errors=new ArrayList<String>() );

errors.add("Invalid Username/Password. Kindly retry");
```

**JSP:**

```
<s:iterator var="msg" value="#session.errorMessages" >
     <p> ${msg} </p>
</s:iterator>
<s:set scope="session" var="errorMessages" value="%{null}" /><%--flush errors--%>
```