# Action error is empty when using Struts 2 dispatcher result

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, error-handling, actionresult

I am not getting action error, when I am using `dispatcher` result in Struts 2.

In action class, the below code is used to add error message.

```
addActionError("Error");
return "Failure";
```

In Struts config:

```
...
<result name="Failure" type="dispatcher">/ShowError.do</result>
...
<action name="ShowError">
    <result>/jsp/ShowActionErrror.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In `ShowActionErrror.jsp`:

```
<div class="error"><s:actionerror /></div>
```

But, I am not getting action error message in `ShowActionErrror.jsp`?

Comment: To use the dispatcher with actions you need to configure your container to process forwards through your S2 filter. In general I recommend against it, though.

Answer (score 4):

Dispatcher is the default Struts2 [Result Type](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/result-types.html).

It is used to execute the standard behavior, from ***Action to JSP***.

Special results are needed to perform other operations like ***Action to Action to JSP***, like `RedirectAction` Result, `Chain` Result (discouraged), etc. Please note that you will lose the `Value Stack` objects (hence the ActionErrors and ActionMessages) [during this kind of routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258530/how-to-pass-actionmessage-and-actionerror-in-redirect-action).

In your case, you should simply use the default Dispatcher Result Type:

```
<result name="Failure" type="dispatcher">/jsp/ShowActionErrror.jsp</result>
```

or simply

```
<result name="Failure">/jsp/ShowActionErrror.jsp</result>
```

Read more on [Result Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/result-configuration.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use `dispatcher` result type with JSPs

```
<result name="Failure" type="dispatcher">/jsp/ShowActionErrror.jsp</result>
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried with JSP It's working fine. But why it is not working with action ?

Comment: Because dispatcher isn't intended to forward to another action.

Comment: @john Struts2 discourages the action chaining in any way, and you even didn't configure the action you talking about. Looking at the code in your question non-Struts1 user will mean that you used the `dispatcher` result with the location `/ShowError.do`, and Struts2 will not serve it because it doesn't accept forwarded requests.